# File ownership issues on PC shared folder

Tags: macos, windows, permission, sharing

I have a shared folder on my Mac that I use to transfer files from a PC. However, when the files come across, they only have the ownership of the PC user account and 'everyone' has no access. My user is missing. Is there anyway to make it automatic that all files transferred to that shared folder from the PC gain the desired ownership/permissions?

`sudo chown` is a bit clunky to have to implement every time.

There used to be a droplet utility called Chop that you could just drag files or folders onto and it would change permissions recursively. Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `setuid` bit on the directory files are being dropped in, and set the owner of the folder appropriately.

```
$ mkdir test
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x  2 mwilson  staff  64 Feb  5 10:14 test/
$ chmod +s test
$ ls -ld test   
drwsr-sr-x  2 mwilson  staff  64 Feb  5 10:14 test/
```

See the man page for `chmod`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion (see below) but still no luck.

drwsr-sr-x+  10 rusty  staff         340  6 Feb 15:17 SCAN SHARE

When the PC creates a new file in the directory it is still owned by the PC user account.
 
 :SCAN SHARE rusty$ 

-rw-------  1 asus   staff   161532930  6 Feb 15:18 test vuescan.tif